# No se ejecuta el metodo 'onreadystatechange' de XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, html, http

Tengo este código que simplifiqué para averiguar por qué no funciona, pero todavía no encuentro el error. Puse un `alert()` después del método `onreadystatechange` y comprobé que no llega nunca a ejecutarse. ¿Por qué puede ser?

localhost/carpeta/http.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>

    function func(url){

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange(function(){
            alert('Esto no se ejecuta nunca');

            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){

               document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

            }
        });

        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send();
    }

    </script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<span style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline"
    onclick="func('test.php?ptr=argumento')">
        Hacer una petición
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

localhost/carpeta/test.php:

```
<?php echo "GET = " . $_GET['ptr']; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes cambiar la forma en la que asignas la función de ajax, es decir, no la coloques entre paréntesis sino asígnala con el operador "=", de la siguiente manera:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        alert('Esto no se ejecuta nunca');
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
           document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Uhh mirá lo que era. Estuve media hora renegando por eso... Gracias!